# HTML, what element is this one?

Tags: html

I tried finding which element/tag is this one but I couldn't find it anywhere.
See the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It is impossible to answer precisely only with a screenshot there are several ways to make such elements. Are you asking how to make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be `range` tag:[link](http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-range.php)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a jQuery UI element rather than an HTML element.

See this link for more details : [JQueryUI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/)